# Abrir arquivo em Python só funciona com pastas do Windows em inglês

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm

Eu tenho um programa de Python que pede um caminho de arquivo ao usuário e mostra os conteúdos do arquivo na tela. O problema é que o código só funciona quando eu coloco os nomes das pastas do Windows em inglês.

Por exemplo:

```
>>> print(open('C:\\Usuários\\usuario\\Documentos\\Gamepobre.txt').read())
```

retorna um erro:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Usuários\\usuario\\Documentos\\Gamepobre.txt'
```

Mas se eu trocar Usuários e Documentos por Users e Documents:

```
>>> print(open('C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documents\\Gamepobre.txt').read())
```

Ele mostra os conteúdos na tela como o esperado.

Como o programa vai usar input de usuário, existe alguma maneira de converter o caminho em português para o equivalente em inglês e evitar esse erro? Pesquisei mas não achei nada que menciona isso na internet.

Desculpe se isso for incrivelmente óbvio. Estou começando ainda. Também estou usando Pycharm, caso isso ajude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que os nomes corretos, verdadeiros, das pastas que você citou, são os nomes em inglês mesmo, `Users` e `Documents`.

O que ocorre é que existe um gancho de visualização definido nos arquivos ocultos `desktop.ini`:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21770
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-112
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-235
```

Essa linha `LocalizedResourceName` chama uma função na `shell32.dll` exatamente no momento da exibição do nome da pasta. Essa função cria a ilusão de um nome traduzido.

Ou seja, no windows explorer e derivados, vai ser exibido um nome ilusório, diferente do verdadeiro nome que a pasta tem. Isso é apenas uma ilusão e não é o nome verdadeiro da pasta.

A forma mais direta de resolver o problema é a utilização de uma interface gráfica baseada no windows explorer para que o usuário selecione a pasta. Por exemplo:

```
from tkinter import filedialog as dlg
path = dlg.askopenfilename()
```

O código acima vai exibir uma janela gráfica para que o usuário selecione um arquivo graficamente. Como essa janela utilizará o windows explorer internamente, os nomes aparecerão traduzidos. Mesmo que o usuário selecione a pasta `Documentos`, a função retornará `Documents`, ou seja, a tradução ocorre automaticamente.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! é uma solução bem melhor. Mas só para completar, existiria alguma maneira de traduzir os nomes das pastas de uma string se eu teoricamente decidisse não usar esta solução, ou eu teria que programar tudo à mão?

Comment: Na verdade acho que nem programando à mão isso é possível @Fupi - a `shell32.dll` pode ter qualquer tipo de ilusão programada, traduções para qualquer língua ou inclusive outras coisas. O único jeito de saber como uma pasta vai aparecer "ilusoriamente" para o usuário que usa o windows explorer é perguntando para o próprio windows explorer, já que ele não mostra os nomes verdadeiros das pastas. O usuário é enganado a pensar que a pasta tem um nome, quando na verdade ela tem outro nome. Imagine que o seu código está rodando em um windows em japonês - teria todas as traduções de todas as pastas?

Answer (score 0):

Para obtero caminho da pasta *usuário* em Windows ou *user* em Unix/Linux use a função de manipulação de caminhos `expanduser` ([https://docs.os.path.html#os.path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)) que substitui o `~` pelo caminho da pasta usuário.

```
from os.path import expanduser
print(open(expanduser("~\\Documentos\\Gamepobre.txt").read())
```

Comment: Mereci a negativação por desatenção. Não levei em conta a pasta **documentos**:
O correto seria:
`import winshell
print  winshell.my_documents ()`

Comment: Não fui eu que negativei mas acho que a sua resposta não responde a pergunta. Não se trata de conseguir o caminho da pasta de documentos, e sim permitir que o usuário entre um caminho em português e ter esse caminho traduzido para poder usá-lo em funções como `open`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Boa tarde tchê.  [Veja essa pergunta:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/375718/como-eu-fa%c3%a7o-pra-quebrar-uma-string-em-v%c3%a1rias-substrings-para-que-eu-possa-traba) Entenda a tendencia dos outros operadores em apenas responder sobre uma quebra de linha para uma variável.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Só que a pergunta abrange mais coisas, ainda não respondidas, como: captação de argumentos (vide *"usuário digitasse"*), e manipulação de substring (novas variáveis: *"uma string em várias substrings para que eu possa trabalhar com cada uma delas separadamente"*).Pergunto: pode responder essa pergunta? Tenho interesse na resposta/código! zObrigado de qualquer forma!