# Como eu faço pra quebrar uma string em várias substrings para que eu possa trabalhar com cada uma delas separadamente utilizando a linguagem C?

Tags: c

ex: Suponhamos que o usuário digitasse "Eu sou bonito".
Então, eu trabalharia com o "Eu", depois com o "sou" e por ultimo com o "bonito", separadamente.

Comment: mostre o código que você tentou fazer até agora

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do André Lins é a mais pertinente em termos de portabilidade, mas é bom saber que a função **strtok()** é uma função considerada **destrutiva** porque ela modifica o primeiro parâmetro passado além de não ser thread-safe (Existem opções como **strtok_r()** e **strtok_s()** que mitiga alguns dos problemas). A função mais indicada para trabalhar para explosão de Strings é **strsep()** que embora não pertença ao standard, ela é a menos problemática e possui algumas vantagens interessantes como o uso de vários delimitadores sem muita dor de cabeça:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *string = strdup("Eu sou bonito,porque sim!Olha só.");
    const char del[] = " .,!";
    char *occor;

    while( (occor = strsep(&string,del)) != NULL )
        printf("%s\n",occor);

    return(0);
}
```

Cada iteração retorna uma fração da string até que a string tenha sido consumida.

Uma implementação usável desta função pode ser encontrada neste link: https://github.com/robertbachmann/openbsd-libc/blob/master/string/strsep.c

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução usando a função strpbrk, que é padrão C, e é não destrutiva.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char teste[] = "aaa1bbb2ccc3ddd";
  char* ptr1 = teste;
  char* ptr2;

  while ((ptr2 = strpbrk(ptr1, "1234567890")) != NULL)
  {
    int size = ptr2 - ptr1;
    printf("%.*s\n", size, ptr1);
    ptr1 = ++ptr2;
  }

  if (ptr1 != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", ptr1);
}
```

Teste:

```
$./371718 
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Observações.

O formato "%.5s\n" formata uma string com tamanho fixo de 5 caracteres. Por exemplo, `printf("%.5s", "1234567890");` vai formatar "12345" na saída.

O formato "%.*s\n" formata uma string com tamanho fixo, com o tamanho indicado pelo parâmetro anterior ao parâmetro ponteiro da string.  Por exemplo, no comando `printf("%.*s", size, "1234567890");` o tamanho da string formatada vai ser indicado pelo valor da variável "size".

Comment: @It Wasn't Me: strpbrk(___, " "))

Comment: não entendi a pergunta...mas existem 3 funções em C que podem ser usadas para estas manipulações, e que são em geral pouco conhecidas: strpbrk (nunca usei), strspn e strcspn...com estas 3 funções dá pra se fazer esse tipo de manipulação, mas mesmo assim a coisa toda é meio braçal

Comment: continuo não entendo...eu usei números, mas poderia ter usado "xk9;z1," por exemplo, apenas para ilustrar que a função strpbrk utiliza um conjunto de delimitadores, e não apenas 1 delimitador

Comment: @It Wasn't Me: isso é bom ou ruim ? (acho que nunca entendo o que você escreve)

Comment: Tchê, isso é bom, visto que atende/responde!!!

Comment: pelo que entendi da pergunta a digitação é feita dentro do programa, e não recebida como parâmetro na linha de comando, mas para pegar da linha de comando é trivial, usando os parâmetros argc e argv da função main

Comment: @It Wasn't Me:  não "automáticamente", na linha deste comando `printf("%.*s\n", size, ptr1);` poderíamos salvar a substring para uso posterior; sugiro que você tente fazer um pequeno programa de teste (um "poc") com suas dúvidas, e abra uma pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função `strtok` da biblioteca `string.h` da maneira abaixo, essa função retorna um ponteiro para o primeiro token encontrado na string, e cada nova interação ele retorna o próximo token:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char text[] = "Eu sou bonito";
  char *textSplit;
  textSplit = strtok(text, " ");

  while (textSplit != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", textSplit);
    textSplit = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  return 0;
}
```